# Tableau Parameter Help. I added a parameter as a filter and it is not working as expected

Tags: dashboard, tableau-desktop

I have the following snippet. Basically, I am creating a new calculated field.

The goal: I am managing a transportation company. I want to charge clients heading North of my town 50$ on top of the base fare, but only from 01JAN24-09JAN24. Then, I want to charge the same amount to clients heading south, but only from 16DEC23-23DEC32 and from 26DEC23-30DEC23. If the clients do business outside the speicifc dates or directions, the surcharge is only $20.

**Snippet**

> [Base Fare]>0 AND [Region]="Arizona" And [Direction] = 'Northbound' AND [Transportation Date] >= DATE(2024-01-01) AND [Transportation Date] <= DATE(2024-01-09)

> Then [Base Fare]+ 50

> ELSEIF
> [Base Fare]>0 AND [Region]="Arizona" And [Direction] = 'Southbound' AND ([Transportation Date] >= DATE(2023-12-16) AND [Transportation Date] <= DATE(2023-12-23)) OR
> ([Transportation Date] >= DATE(2023-12-26) AND [Transportation Date] <= DATE(2023-12-30))

> Then [Base Fare]+ 50

> ELSE
> [Base Fare]+ 20
> END
> **End of Snippet**

I also added a Parameter called "Direction", where I want to click "Northbound" or "Southbound". The goal is for my data dashboard to show the "Final price charged", depending on Northbound or Southbound.

**Problem**: When I click the parameter, the data doesnt change. Its not distinguishing Northbound from Southbound.
[image: Filters here]

Code and problem is above in details :)

Comment: Can you please share the workbook via Tableau Public? It helps

Comment: You might want to add more details in the following format 1.What are the columns that are present in the existing data? 2.What is the granularity of the data? 3.When you want to apply this calculation what is the level of aggregation needed? 4. Is there a column for identifying direction in the data apart from the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the parameter type is Float, but you are using the displayed values in your code? Post a screenshot of the parameter edit screen.